# django: Why transaction.savepoint_rollback(savepoint_id) doesn't rollback the PK (id) sequence in the database?

Tags: python, django, django-models, transactions, psql

I'm using `django 1.9` with `psql`. I'm taking advantage of the `transaction.savepoint_rollback` functionality to create a large number of instances and then rollback the changes.

Everything works as expected. However, I find interesting that this functionality doesn't rollback the `id sequence` for the created model. e.g. if 1000 objects are created and rolled back, the new objects will start with ids greater than 1000.

Wondering if somebody knows how to roll back the IDs or if that isn't possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found this is not really a `django` related situation. I found this [discussion](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/501B1494.9040502@ringerc.id.au):

> The general idea with sequences is that they produce numbers that can be 
>   meaningfully compared for equality and for greater/less-than, but *not* 
>   for distance from each other. Because they're exempt from transactional 
>   rollback you shouldn't use them when you need a gap-less sequence of 
>   numbers.
>
> It's usually a sign of an application design problem when you need a 
>   gapless sequence. Try to work out a way to do what you need when there 
>   can be gaps. Sometimes it's genuinely necessary to have gapless 
>   sequences though - for example, when generating cheque or invoice numbers.